# Where is git command after installing "GitHub for Windows"?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github, github-for-windows

After installing `GitHub for Windows`, I can use `git` command in `Powershell` directly:

```
C:\Users\xiaona\Documents\GitHub> git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
   add        Add file contents to the index
   bisect     Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
......
```

But where is the `git` command installed? I can't find it in `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking, it should under:

```
%LocalAppData%\GitHub
```

For example, in my PC, it is:

```
C:\Users\xiaona\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin
```

Answer (score 2):

In my PC is here:

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\GitHub

Comment: In my PC, it is: C:\Users\xiaona\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin。